# Enumerable select method to change values in list

Tags: c#, linq, list

(A down vote requires explanation please )

simple question: what is wrong with my Linq. I want the values of a list to be replaced by its index. Simple as I thought:

```
var dd = myList.Select((x, i) => new {x=i});
```

`dd` is empty. I am not expert of Linq, and I am learning how it works.

Comment: What do you mean by 'empty'? `dd` is an `IEnumerable<'a>` so you need to iterate over to access any elements in it.

Comment: What actually are you trying to do? a list of `0 to n`? funny guy

Comment: nah, i want to operate on values of x based on it index. Like x = 10, if index is a multiple of 42,

Comment: @Lee yes. well, stupid me.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use linq to modify the collection. Linq is for querying, it is not designed to modify the collection.

LINQ => **Language-Integrated Query**

"Q" stands for "Query".

And for your question I don't think it makes sense. Index would be "0 - count-1"

```
var dd = Enumerable.Range(0, myList.Count).ToList();
```

this should do that.

---

I think you mean this ?

```
var dd = myList.Select((x, i) => new { Value = x, Index = i}).ToList();
```

Comment: I know how to use Range. What i want to do is different issue, but answer to my small question solves rest of the problem. Further, I know what Linq stands for, as i mentioned in the question, I am learning Linq and I want to see how it works.

Comment: @Naresh See, there is nothing to be "rude", It won't help you to get answer anyway. How about explaining your question clearly? I answered your question perfectly what is being asked.

Comment: @Naresh Flagged as rude.. Be polite. Try to explain well rather than downvoting people who show interest to help you.

Comment: And i appreciate it. thanks a lot. but rather than answering my question, i got tips from several people. as far as i think, my question was clear. the upvote/downvote fucntion is for clarity and completeness of Q&A, not quality of solutions as far as i think.

Comment: that is your opinion sir. And I was not rude. I was clear and to the point.

Comment: and yes, your updated answer helped me. your first one was not the answer.

Comment: @Naresh I assumed and answered in last part of my answer, "I want the values of a list to be replaced by its index" What do you meant by replaced by its index? IMO this is not clear.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel simple question: what is wrong with my Linq? This the first line sir. and I want correction in my Linq, since I am learning, I want to see what is wrong here, coz i didnt see anything wrong. Do you get my point. I want to know the mistakes in my line of code. as simple as that. of course, if I want more details about Linq, I will study up. Here at stackoverflow, I ask when I get struck/silly. And I dont think I am wrong about it. Correct me if I am.

Comment: Well that part and all clear, nothing wrong. Confusing part is this "I want the values of a list to be replaced by its index." By this what I understand is you want to overwrite your list with indexes. and indexes will be `0-n` hence I suggested `Enumerable.Range`. Am I being wrong anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Linq shouldn't be used for modifying collections. You can use [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) to make a new list with the indices.

```
var dd = myList.Select((x, i) => i).ToList();
```

Regarding your comment

> I want to operate on values of x based on it index.

This would conventionally be done with a `foreach` loop, but it is possible to use `Select`

```
var dd = items.Select((x, i) => i % 42 == 0 ? 10 : x);
```

or more generally

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Replace<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> collection,
        Func<T, bool> predicate,
        T value
    )
    {
        return collection.Select((x, i) => predicate(x) ? value : x);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Replace<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> collection,
        Func<T, int, T> predicate,
        T value
    )
    {
        return collection.Select((x, i) => predicate(x, i) ? value : x);
    }
}

var dd = items.Replace((x, i) => i % 42 == 0, 10);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var dd = myList.Select(i => myList.IndexOf(i));
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Downvoters care to comment? I am doing exactly what the question asks

Comment: Am not the downvoter but this is poor performing. Check my answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think it's because there are better ways of getting the index.

Comment: @gleng This is not twice, It is O(n * n) isn't it?